# Recycler view adapter now displaying data in fragment

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am trying to display data from my database in my fragment through recycler view. I used a for loop to go through all the users in my database. All the users who are neither friends nor have sent requests should be displayed as implemented in the `if` condition of fragment class. The code for fragment class is written below.

```
public class AddMemberFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private View view ;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    String userId;
    String n_team ;
    ArrayList<Friend> friends;


    public AddMemberFragment() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addnewfriend_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        userId = firebaseUser.getUid();
        ManageTeamTabbedActivity activity = (ManageTeamTabbedActivity) getActivity();
        n_team = activity.getMyData();
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.addNewFriend);
        //mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);//
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        friends = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new AddMemberAdapter(getActivity(), friends, n_team) ;
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mRootRef.child("users");
        mRootRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ArrayList<Friend> friendArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                DataSnapshot friendsData = dataSnapshot.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("friends");
                DataSnapshot requests = null;
                DataSnapshot currentFriends = null;
                if (friendsData.hasChild("requests")) {
                    requests = dataSnapshot.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("friends").child("requests");
                }
                if (friendsData.hasChild("currentFriends")) {
                    currentFriends = dataSnapshot.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("friends").child("currentFriends");
                }

                for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.d("demo", "USERID " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                    Friend friend = new Friend();
                    if ((userSnapshot.getKey().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())) || (requests != null && requests.hasChild(userSnapshot.getKey()))
                            || (currentFriends != null && currentFriends.hasChild(userSnapshot.getKey()))) {

                    } else {
                        friend.setId(userSnapshot.getKey());
                        friend.setFriendName((String) userSnapshot.child("profiles").child("fname").getValue());
                        friendArrayList.add(friend);
                    }
                }
                friends = friendArrayList;
                if (friends != null && !friends.isEmpty()) {
                    mAdapter.setFriendList(friends);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the corresponding adapter code is written here :

```
public class AddMemberAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AddMemberAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<Friend> mData;
    private Context mContext;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private String u_team ;

    public AddMemberAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Friend> friendList , String u_team) {
        this.mData = friendList;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.u_team= u_team;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.addnewfriend_layout, parent, false);
        AddMemberAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder = new AddMemberAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Friend frnd =(Friend) mData.get(position);

        holder.friendName.setText(frnd.getFriendName());
        holder.addFriend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                frnd.setStatus("sent");
                final DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                final String UID = firebaseUser.getUid();
                mRootRef.child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        mRootRef.child("users").child(UID).child("friends").child("requests").child(frnd.getId()).setValue(frnd);
                        Friend temp = new Friend();
                        temp.setId(firebaseUser.getUid());
                        temp.setFriendName(firebaseUser.getDisplayName());
                        temp.setStatus("received");
                        mRootRef.child("users").child(frnd.getId()).child("friends").child("requests").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(temp);
                        mData.remove(frnd);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override

                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView friendName;
        ImageButton addFriend;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            friendName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFriendName);
            addFriend = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagebuttonFriendAdd);
        }
    }

    public void setFriendList(ArrayList<Friend> friendList){
        this.mData = friendList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

The output I am getting is attached here.

[image]

Users who are not friends and have not been sent friend requests by the current user should have been displayed in this Add New Member fragment through this `RecyclerView`. I tried to debug it myself and removed the if condition but it did not work either. Please guide how to display it. The

The database screenshot is attached as well.

[image]

Comment: The question is not clear. Can you specify exactly what you need to be shown in the list? Also it would be great if you could provide a sample database snapshot from firebase so that we could take a look into the data structure as well.

Comment: Sure. I have edited the question. Users who are not friends and have not been sent friend request by the current user should have been displayed in the Add New Member fragment through this recycler view.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a problem with your firebase query and the data-extraction techniques, however, with this data structure, as the list grows you will have a difficult time getting the list of your friends. From my understanding, it is just taking a lot of time to display the list in that fragment.

Also, you might consider setting up the adapter with the `RecyclerView` while you are initializing the `RecyclerView`.

You might consider doing something like the following.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    userId = firebaseUser.getUid();
    ManageTeamTabbedActivity activity = (ManageTeamTabbedActivity) getActivity();
    n_team = activity.getMyData();
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.addNewFriend);
    // mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); // Remove this line
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // Set the adapter here with an empty list first. 
    friends = new ArrayList<>();
    mAdapter = new AddMemberAdapter(getActivity(), friends, n_team);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mRootRef.child("users");
    mRootRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayList<Friend> friendArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            DataSnapshot friendsData = dataSnapshot.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("friends");
            DataSnapshot requests = null;
            DataSnapshot currentFriends = null;
            if (friendsData.hasChild("requests")) {
                requests = dataSnapshot.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("friends").child("requests");
            }
            if (friendsData.hasChild("currentFriends")) {
                currentFriends = dataSnapshot.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("friends").child("currentFriends");
            }

            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d("demo", "USERID " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                Friend friend = new Friend();
                if ((userSnapshot.getKey().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())) || (requests != null && requests.hasChild(userSnapshot.getKey()))
                        || (currentFriends != null && currentFriends.hasChild(userSnapshot.getKey()))) {

                } else {
                    friend.setId(userSnapshot.getKey());
                    friend.setFriendName((String) userSnapshot.child("profiles").child("fname").getValue());
                    friendArrayList.add(friend);
                }
            }
            friends = friendArrayList;
            if (friends != null && !friends.isEmpty()) {
                mAdapter.setFriendList(friends); // Set the friend list to the adapter when the list is loaded. 
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

And in your adapter, you will need a function to set the friends' list and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

```
// In your adapter class, add the following method. 
public void setFriendList(ArrayList<Friend> friendList) {
    this.mData = friendList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: I tried with this and its giving an error  cannot find symbol method setFriendList(ArrayList<Friend>). Although I have imported ava.util.ArrayList .

Comment: Looks like you did not add the method in your adapter class as a `public` method. Hence while you are trying to access it from your activity, it could not find that method.

Comment: I defined it in the adapter class.

Comment: What do you mean by `adapter class also`? The function should be in the adapter class only.

Comment: I defined it in the adapter class only. Sorry, mistake in writing that also.

Comment: I see. Can you please update your latest adapter class in your question? Thank you.

Comment: Yes both classes have been updated in the question. Please check. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure why you are not able to access the `setFriendList` method. Can you please try clean/build your project? Thank you!